# EWS Managed API synchronization cache location

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

When using the Exchange Web Services (EWS) Managed API to [synchronize a folder hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693005%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) or [synchronize items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693003%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), where is the client-side cache located?  Is it in-memory only?  Is it on disk?  Is there a way to find or control where the cache is located?  I can't seem to find information on this anywhere.

Comment: What "client-side cache" are you referring to? The article you mention doesn't refer to any such cache, nor does the API documentation for `SyncFolderHierarchy` and `SyncFolderItems`. You'd use the documented approach and APIs to synchronize the contents of (some folders in) a mailbox from Exchange to whatever system you'd like to store them in.

Comment: That's sort of my question: what is the client-side cache? (which isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation)  What client-side data store is the server-side data being synchronized to?

Comment: The API simply allows you to access the data in Exchange. It's synchronized that whatever **you** synchronize it to. The article describes synchronization, because that is the common use-case for it (you get a state "cookie" back with every call that allows you to continue from that point).

Comment: You might also be served by this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn440953(v=exchg.150).aspx. It describes the whole approach to synchronization from a somewhat higher level and with (in my opinion) better examples.

Comment: Yes, I've read that and a million other articles.  Are you saying that the client-side synchronization cache is nothing more than the ChangeCollection<ItemChange>?

Comment: This article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn440952%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx has a nice diagram showing two different synchronization patterns: initial synchronization, and ongoing synchronization. Ongoing synchronization implies there is some kind of semi-persistent client-side cache that is receiving deltas.

Comment: Or does "synchronization" really mean "just send me deltas and a timestamp and I'll do what I want with the deltas"?  That would explain my confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59770/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-oran).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SyncFolderHierarchy` and `SyncFolderItems` together allow you to efficiently synchronize the contents of all (or a subset of the) folders in a mailbox in Exchange.

The flow indicated in the articles is indicative. The call to `SyncFolderItems` returns a `ChangeCollection<T>` with items of type `ItemChange` or `FolderChange`. If you process these items, you can pull down additional information on the folders or for example the actual contents of each item in the folder.

After you've processed the `ChangeCollection`, you're supposed to store the `SyncState` value somewhere. The next time you call `SyncFolderItems` you pass in that value and Exchange will return you the next batch of items.

Since it's likely that (especially the first time you synchronize) there are more items than `SyncFolderItems` can return in a single call, you should check [`MoreChangesAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd636158(v=exchg.80).aspx) to determine if there's more to do.

So all in all that turns into this loop:

```
// Track whether there are more items available for download on the server.
bool moreChangesAvailable = false;
do {
    // Get a list of all items in the Inbox by calling SyncFolderHierarchy repeatedly until no more changes are available.
    // The folderId parameter must be set to the root folder to synchronize,
    // and must be same folder ID as used in previous synchronization calls. 
    // The propertySet parameter is set to IdOnly to reduce calls to the Exchange database,
    // because any additional properties result in additional calls to the Exchange database. 
    // The ignoredItemIds parameter is set to null, so that no items are ignored.
    // The maxChangesReturned parameter is set to return a maximum of 10 items (512 is the maximum).
    // The syncScope parameter is set to Normal items, so that associated items will not be returned.
    // The syncState parameter is set to cSyncState, which should be null in the initial call, 
    // and should be set to the sync state returned by the 
    // previous SyncFolderItems call in subsequent calls.
    ChangeCollection<ItemChange> icc = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox), PropertySet.IdOnly, null, 10, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, cSyncState);

    // If the count of changes is zero, there are no changes to synchronize.
    if (icc.Count <> 0) {
        // Otherwise, write all the changes included in the response to the console. 
        foreach (ItemChange ic in icc) {
            Console.WriteLine("ChangeType: " + ic.ChangeType.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + ic.ItemId);
        }
    }

    // Save the sync state for use in future SyncFolderContent requests.
    // The sync state is used by the server to determine what changes to report
    // to the client.
    string sSyncState = icc.SyncState;

   // Determine whether more changes are available on the server.
   moreChangesAvailable = icc.MoreChangesAvailable;
}
while (moreChangesAvailable);
```

*Code sample [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn440953(v=exchg.150).aspx), since I can't say it better than they do*.

So there is no such thing as a client-side cache, unless you choose to store the items client-side yourself. If you choose not to store them, you can simply continue the loop until you reach the point where the stuff that you're interested in starts. The code above for example doesn't download anything, except the `ItemChange` records and the ID (indicated by `PropertySet.IdOnly`) of each item.

This [MSDN article provides a great overview of the synchronization process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn440952%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent answer.  I had an incorrect mental model from the API's use of the word "sync" which implies keeping client-side and server-side states fully synced.  But now I understand that these Sync* calls are really just returning deltas from after the last SyncState timestamp and it's up to you whether you want to use the deltas to maintain your own "synced" copy or just pick and choose what you want to read from the deltas.  For others who are reading, see the chat for more helpful details: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59770/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-oran